# is there a way to print lightning web component to pdf

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning, lwc

I am trying to print lwc component to pdf, don't want to use vf page as it will require us to maintain field additions in both lwc as well as vf page.
I tried using jspdf library , but can't query element and print. Below is the js function I have been trying to work,

```js
generatePdf(){
     var source = window.document.getElementsByTagName('c-org_roll-entry-details');
     var specialElementHandlers = {
         '#hidden-element': function (element, renderer) {
             return true;
         }
     };
    const { jsPDF } = window.jspdf;
    const pdf = new jsPDF({
    });
    pdf.fromHTML(source, 15, 15, {
      'width': 170,
      'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
  });
    pdf.save('summary.pdf');
    //console.log(pdf.output('datauristring'));

    
}
```